# Jira api /search issue - does not exist or this field cannot be viewed by anonymous users

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have a rest API call that worked on self-hosted Jira, but when used on atlassian.net I get

My request:
`POST /rest/api/2/search`
with body:

```json
{
    "jql": "worklogAuthor = currentUser() AND worklogDate = 2022-09-30 ORDER BY updated ASC",
    "fields":
    [
        "worklog"
    ]
}
```

and the error I get:

```json
{
    "errorMessages":
    [
        "Field 'worklogAuthor' does not exist or this field cannot be viewed by anonymous users.",
        "Field 'worklogDate' does not exist or this field cannot be viewed by anonymous users."
    ],
    "warningMessages":
    []
}
```

In self-hosted solution I used my username and password, on attlasian.net I used https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens to generate a personal token that I used instead of a password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To authenticate on Jira cloud using basic authentication, you will use:

**email** *rather than username*

**token** *rather than password*